# sharing core data datamodel between 2 iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, data-modeling

I'm new to coredata, so maybe one can tell me if what I plan makes sense or if there is another best practice to do it, so:
Basically I am building 2 apps: one is getting data from various sources, puts them together and drops them into a core data datamodel. Since this takes its time I want this to run once in the simulator in a seperate app.

The other app is going to be shipped with that data ( and datamodel)
So: two apps sharing the datamodel (and custom managedObject classes) and the sqlite file.

I don't want to rebuild the datamodel in the second app and keep the two in sync manually of course - so:

How do I do this ?
simply by adding the custom classes and .xcdatamodel file to the other project (without copying) and changing the filenames in the managedObjectModel and persistentStoreCoordinator Methods in the app Delegate to mach the file name of the datamodelfile from the first app?

sounds a bit odd to me...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only sharing resources during development, in Xcode, then yes you will be able to share the same CD resources between Xcode projects. Just be sure that when you add the files to a new project that you *uncheck* the "copy items into destination group's folder", but beyond that it's not much tweaking to make it all work properly.

If you are talking about sharing CD resources during runtime on the iPhone, that isn't possible as @Björn stated in his answer.

Comment: thanks for the clarification - I am just thinking about sharing for development.

Comment: Caution: when adding a new model version in one project, it won't be added automatically to the other. You will have to remove the storage from the second project, and drag it back into the second project from finder.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you should be able to share data via App Groups now.

Answer (score 1):

Every App runs inside it's own sandbox, there is no way of sharing data between Apps without putting some kind of "middle man" between them to keep them in synch (a webserver for example).

Comment: ah. ok seems my question was wrongleading. I only want to share while developing - not at runtime. I want to put the data together and use the same datamodel for deeloping the second app. so when I change something in the datamodel of the first app, I dont have to update anything in the second app